# Davenport's proof of the Hadamard theorem

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-explanation, entire-functions

In [Multiplicative Number Theory](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-1-4757-5927-3), H. Davenport proves the following theorem in the paragraph §11 (page 74) :

> **Theorem :** *(Hadamard)*
>
> *Let $f:\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}$ be entire of order $\leqslant1$ (that is, $f(z)\in O(\exp[s^{1+\varepsilon}])$ for all $\varepsilon>0$) with $f(0)\neq0$. Then, there exists constants $A,B$ such that $$f(z)=e^{A+Bz}\prod_{\rho}\left(1-\frac{z}{\rho}\right)e^{z/\rho},$$
> where the product ranges over all zeroes of $f$.*

This theorem makes use of [Jensen's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_formula). In its proof, he tries to show that the product part, defined as $P(z)$, is such that $f/P$ is entire of order $\leqslant1$. Since it has no zeroes (those of $f$ are cancelled by the product), it will turn out that $f/P$ must have the form $e^{A+Bz}$. However, there are two things I'm concerned about :

1. He has shown that $|P(z)|>\exp(R^{-1+3\varepsilon})$ on $|z|=R_n$, for infintely many $R_n$ where $R_n\underset{n\to+\infty}{\longrightarrow}+\infty$. He then concludes that $f/P$ must have order $\leqslant1$. But for this, we would need to prove that the $\limsup$ of $|\exp(-z^{1+4\varepsilon})f(z)/P(z)|$ is finite. This only proves that *one* accumulation point is finite, doesn't it ? *How to prove that the $\limsup$ is finite ?**
2. When handling the case for $P_3(s)$, he basically writes that $(1-u)e^{-u}\geqslant e^{-cu^2}$ for some constant $c$, where $u\in]0,1/2[$. (*There used to be a typo here in my original question, which I commented about in Daniel's answer...*) However, this seems to be impossible ; I tried computing $\displaystyle\inf_{0<u<1/2}(1-u)e^{-u+cu^2}$ for arbitrarily large values of $c$ with `Wolfram`, and it seems like it's always $<1$ for some $u$ close enough to zero (corresponding to zeroes of $f$ infinitely far away to the origin). **Am I getting something wrong, or is this *really* a mistake ?**

I have [uploaded](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/418131142923780106/746065739798020227/Davenport-Hadamard.pdf) the extracted pages from the book so people don't owning a digital/printed copy of the book can still follow along. Is this against the rules ? If so, I'll just remove it.

Comment: Regarding point 1, What do you think about the comment "We observe. for future reference, that in the preceding argument it suffices if the estimate for J(z) on Izl = R holds for some sequence of values of R with limit' infinity. instead of for all large R." Given this we do not need to worry about lim sup, do we?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't looked at how Davenport argues, but if I interpret [rain1's comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3797805/davenports-proof-of-the-hadamard-theorem#comment7824842_3797805) correctly, he earlier remarked that it suffices to have the estimate on some unbounded family of radii. There are many ways to see that. One can use [Hadamard's three circle theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_three-circle_theorem) to interpolate between $R_n$ and $R_{n+1}$. Alternatively, with
$$\frac{f(z)}{P(z)} = e^{g(z)}$$
the estimates on the circles $\lvert z\rvert = R_n$ give upper bounds for $\operatorname{Re} g(z)$ on these circles. Then for example the [Borel–Carathéodory theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel%E2%80%93Carath%C3%A9odory_theorem) gives you upper bounds for $\lvert g(z)\rvert$ on discs, say with radius $R_n/2$, from which you can obtain the desired bounds. Another method uses properties of (real-valued) harmonic functions. The upper bounds for $\operatorname{Re} g(z)$ on the circles $\lvert z\rvert = R_n$ then show that that is a polynomial (in $x,y$) whose degree is in this case at most $1$. From that it follows that $g$ is a polynomial (in $z$) of the same degree. (Pedantic note: If $\operatorname{Re} g(z) \equiv 0$, then $g$ may have degree $0$, which is larger than the degree of the zero polynomial.)

Concerning the second point, it is useful to take the logarithm. We have
\begin{align}
\log \bigl((1-u)e^{u}\bigr)
&= u + \log (1-u) \\
&= u - \sum_{k = 1}^{\infty} \frac{u^k}{k} \\
&= -\sum_{k = 2}^{\infty} \frac{u^k}{k} \\
&> -\frac{u^2}{2} \sum_{m = 0}^{\infty} u^m \\
&= -\frac{u^2}{2(1-u)} \\
&> -u^2
\end{align}
for $u \in \mathopen{]}0, 1/2\mathclose{[}$, thus every $c \geqslant 1$ works.

Regarding the edit, the minus sign in the exponent is a typo. For $(1-u)e^{-u} = 1 - 2u + O(u^2)$ we cannot have a lower bound of the form $e^{-cu^2} = 1 - cu^2 + O(u^4)$, and since there may be infinitely many factors to estimate, a bound $(1 - u)e^{-u} \geqslant ae^{-cu^2}$ with an $a \in (0,1)$ doesn't help.

The factors in the product have the form $(1 - u)e^{u}$ with $u = \frac{z}{\rho}$. The factor $e^{z/\rho}$ in that guarantees convergence of the product by ensuring that the full factors have an asymptotic expansion of $1 - O\bigl(\frac{z^2}{\rho^2}\bigr)$, and $\sum \frac{1}{\lvert \rho\rvert^2}$ converges for an entire function of order $\leqslant 1$, while $\sum \frac{1}{\lvert \rho\rvert}$ may diverge. For the estimate of the tail product
$$\prod_{\lvert \rho\rvert > 2R}\biggl(1 - \frac{z}{\rho}\biggr)e^{z/\rho}$$
we must not take the modulus of $z/\rho$ too early, we must estimate the factors as they stand and only replace $z/\rho$ with its modulus later.

The first three lines of the above computation are valid for complex $u$ with $\lvert u\rvert < 1$ (using the principal branch of the logarithm), thus we have
$$\bigl\lvert \log \bigl((1 - u)e^{u}\bigr)\bigr\rvert = \Biggl\lvert \sum_{k = 2}^{\infty} \frac{u^k}{k}\Biggr\rvert \leqslant \sum_{k = 2}^{\infty} \frac{\lvert u\rvert^k}{k} \leqslant \lvert u\rvert^2$$
for all complex $u$ with $\lvert u\rvert \leqslant \frac{1}{2}$. From that it follows that
$$- \operatorname{Re} \log \bigl((1-u)e^{u}\bigr) \leqslant \lvert u\rvert^2$$
and therefore
$$\bigl\lvert (1-u)e^{u}\bigr\rvert \geqslant e^{- \lvert u\rvert^2}$$
for these $u$. Thus
$$\Biggl\lvert \prod_{\lvert \rho\rvert > 2R} \biggl(1 - \frac{z}{\rho}\biggr)e^{z/\rho}\Biggr\rvert \geqslant \exp \Biggl(- \sum_{\lvert \rho\rvert > 2R} \frac{\lvert z\rvert^2}{\lvert \rho\rvert^2}\Biggr)\,.$$
In that, we have $\lvert z\rvert = R$, and then we use bounds for the tail sum
$$\sum_{\lvert \rho \rvert > 2R} \frac{1}{\lvert \rho\rvert^2}$$
to obtain the desired estimate.

Comment: Sorry to bother, but I made a huge typo in my question, which I should have noticed when looking at your answer. Now that I took the time to redo the work, I noticed he used that $$(1-u)e^{{\color{red}-}u}\geqslant e^{-cu^2}$$ for some $c$. When asking [Wolfram](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=minimise+%281-x%29*exp%28-x%2B10*x%5E2%29+for+x+in+%5B0%2C1%2F2%5D) to try it out (replace `10` with whatever big number you want), it's never working...

Comment: Borel-Carathéodory was key however, thank you again for this !

Comment: That must be a typo in Davenport's book then. On the one hand, the factors in the product have the form $(1- u)e^{u}$ (with $u = \frac{z}{\rho}$). On the other hand, $(1 - u)e^{-u + cu^2} = 1 - 2u + O(u^2)$, so the minimum is definitely smaller than $1$ with the $e^{-u}$ factor.

Comment: But from $|e^z|=e^{\Re(z)}$, which we may only bound as $\geqslant e^{-|z|}$, there is no way to get that plus sign, is there ? I feel like I'm missing something obvious, but I cannot figure out what...

Comment: The inequality in question is used to estimate $$\Biggl\lvert\prod_{\lvert \rho\rvert > 2R} \biggl(1 - \frac{z}{\rho}\biggr)e^{z/\rho}\Biggr\rvert\,,$$ isn't it?

Comment: Yes, exactly, he shows that this is greater than $\exp(-R^{1+2\varepsilon})$ on $|z|=R$.

Comment: It's a typo (and maybe a badly formulated argument). I'll elaborate a bit on that in an edit, the comments are a bit to constrained for convenience. Will take a couple of minutes.

Comment: Well, for sufficiently large values of "couple" ;) I hope the edit helps. If you have further questions, don't hesitate to ask, but an answer will not be quick since I'm now going to bed.

Comment: This works like a charm, thank you very much, and good night !